# Roots of unity and cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $w$ be a primitive $p$th root of unity and consider the equation $$w^x+w^y+w^z=w^{x+y}+w^{y+z}+w^{z+x},$$ where $x,y$ and $z$ are integers.

Cyclotomic polynomials can be used to settle many cases. For example, for $p$ prime, a solution requires the multiset {$x,y,z$} to be of the form {$0,t,-t$}, modulo $p$.

Is there a neat way to solve the equation for general $p$?

Comment: How did you solve it for general $p$ prime?

Comment: The powers can be replaced by positive integers less than $p$. With all terms on one side, the expression must then be a multiple of   $$1+w+...+w^{p-1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e(x)=\exp(2\pi i x)$ and $U=e({\mathbb Q})$. Putting $a=w^x,b=w^y,c=w^z$, your question can be rephrased as : find all $a,b,c\in U$ such that

$$a+b+c=ab+ac+bc \tag{1}$$.

Now, put $u_1=a,u_2=b,u_3=c,u_4=-ab,u_5=-ac,u_6=-bc$. We have :

**Theorem.** Let $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_6 \in U$. Then $u_1+u_2+\ldots +u_6=0$ iff for some permutation $\sigma$ of $[|1..6|]$, and $v=(u_{\sigma(1)},u_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,u_{\sigma(6)})$ one of the following two holds :

(i) $v=(\rho_1,-\rho_1,\rho_2,-\rho_2,\rho_3,-\rho_3)$, with $\rho_1,\rho_2,\rho_3 \in U$

(ii) $v=(\rho_1,\rho_1 e(\frac{1}{3}),\rho_1 e(\frac{2}{3}),
\rho_2,\rho_2 e(\frac{1}{3}),\rho_2 e(\frac{2}{3}))$, with $\rho_1,\rho_2 \in U$.

(iii) $v=(\rho e(\frac{1}{5}),\rho e(\frac{2}{5}),
\rho e(\frac{3}{5}), \rho e(\frac{4}{5}),-\rho e(\frac{1}{3}),-\rho e(\frac{2}{3}))$, with $\rho \in U$.

**Proof :** see  see Henry B. Mann, "On linear relations between roots of unity", Mathematika 12(1965), pp.107-117.

For shorter formulas, let us put $j=e(\frac{1}{3}),\eta=e(\frac{1}{5})$.
(i) yields the following solutions to (1) :

$$
\lbrace a,b,c \rbrace = \lbrace x,-x,-x^{2} \rbrace,
\lbrace 1,x,x^{-1} \rbrace, \ \textrm{or} \ \lbrace y_1,y_2,y_1y_2 \rbrace,
\ \textrm{with} \ x\in U,y_1=\pm i, y_2=\pm i. \tag{2}
$$

(ii) yields the following solution to (1) :

$$
\lbrace a,b,c \rbrace = \lbrace x,jx,j^2x\rbrace \ \textrm{or} \  \lbrace x,-j,-j^2\rbrace,
\ \textrm{with} \ x\in U. \tag{3}
$$

(iii) yields the following solutions to (1) :

$$
\lbrace a,b,c \rbrace = \lbrace -\eta^x, j^{y}\eta^{2x},j^{y}\eta^{4x}\rbrace,
\ \textrm{with} \ 1 \leq x \leq 4, 1\leq y \leq 2. \tag{4}
$$

Comment: Thanks - the Theorem is just what I needed. A couple of queries though. First, I assume $\exp(2\pi x)$ is $\exp(2\pi xj)$. Also, I don't understand the reference to $\eta=e(\frac{1}{5})$.

Comment: @S.Dolan corrected, thanks. The reference to $e(\frac{1}{5})$ was a left-over from a previous, incorrect version.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I've just worked through solutions (2). I make it $-x^2$ not $x^{-2}$ and $1$ not $i$.

Comment: I've now worked through solutions (3). I believe your answer should be $\lbrace x,xj,xj^2\rbrace,\ \textrm{with} \ x\in U$. Also, there's one further solution, $$\lbrace x,k,k^5\rbrace,\ \textrm{with} \ x\in U,$$ where $k=e(\frac{1}{6})$.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. One last query -sorry! I have requested a copy of the Mann paper from ResearchGate but not yet received it. Am I right in thinking that for 8 roots of unity the only possibilities are 4 pairs of diametrically opposite points, two sets of vertices of equilateral triangles and 1 pair of diametrically opposite points and the vertices of an equilateral triangle plus a regular pentagon? Thanks again.

Comment: Regarding (2) : Typo corrected, thanks. Regarding (3) : $\lbrace x,k,k^5 \rbrace$ is not a new solution, it is the same thing as the $\lbrace x,-j,-j^2 \rbrace$ I wrote, since $k=-j^2,k^5=-j$.

Comment: Regarding your question about length $8$, first of all in length $6$ I forgot the case of the triangle and pentagon intersecting at a point (which is now included in my answer). So in length $8$ you'll also have this case combined with a pair of opposite points. I don't know if this is exahustive, because Mann's effective results unfortunately stop at length $7$.