# Sum of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$. It is well known that 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} e^{2 \pi i \frac{k}{N}} =0. $$
More generally, if $N=pq$ and $P=\{ 0, q,\cdots, (p-1)q \}$, then 
$$ \sum_{k \in P} e^{2 \pi i \frac{k}{N}} =0. $$

**My question** :is the converse true?

If $P \subseteq \{0,1,\cdots,N-1\}$ such that
$$ \sum_{k \in P} e^{2 \pi i \frac{k}{N}} =0, $$
can we show that the set $P$ has the form $P=\{ 0, q,\cdots, (p-1)q \}$ where $N=pq$?

---

The above question is **not true**.

If $P \subseteq \{0,1,\cdots,N-1\}$ such that
$$ \sum_{k \in P} e^{2 \pi i \frac{k}{N}} =0, $$
and **any proper subset of $P$ doesn’t satisfy the equality**, 
can we show that the set $P$ has the form $P=\{ 0, q,\cdots, (p-1)q \}$ where $N=pq$?

Answer (score 1):

No, the converse is not true, because you can take unions of such sets (if $\sum_{k\in P}=0$ and $\sum_{k\in P'}=0$, then $\sum_{k\in P \cup P'}=0$.

For example, if $P=\{ 0, q,\cdots, (p-1)q \} \cup \{ 0, p,\cdots, (q-1)p \}$ (with, say $p=3,q=5$) then $P$ is not of the form you gave.

Comment: If I add a condition that any proper subset of P doesn’t satisfy the equality, can we get the conclusion?

Comment: @wzstrong No, because you can construct some more complicated examples : take $N$ even, $N=2M$ and $$P=\{ q,\cdots, (p-1)q \} \cup \{  p+M,2p+M,\cdots, (q-1)p+M \}$$. For most values of $p,q, M$, the minimal subsets included in this $P$ (often $P$ itself will be minimal) will not be of the form you gave.

Comment: In fact, there exists a proper subset of $P$ satisfying the equality except for $P$ only two element. If we remove some trivial cases, can we obtain some conclusion?

Comment: @wzstrong There is no generic conclusion that I know of. To learn more, you can take a look at my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2700761/roots-of-unity-and-cyclotomic-polynomials/2706413#2706413 (and the reference I gave there)

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\sum_{k\in P} e^{2i\pi k/n}=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1} e^{2i\pi j q/n}=\frac{e^{2i\pi p q/(pq)}-1}{e^{2 i \pi q/(pq)}-1}=\frac{e^{2i\pi}-1}{e^{2 i \pi/p}-1}=0.$$
We have trabsformed the index $k$ to $j$ as $k=jq$ where $j$ goes from $0$ to $p-1$.
Then we used the sum of finite GP, where $n=pq$.